# Instantiate a fragment with a Custom Object Array List

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, instance

I'm trying to instantiate a fragment "sending" a custom object array list, but I can't find the exact way to do it. I think I may have to use `Serializable` or `Parcelable` (as seen in another answer), but I'm not sure how to implement it even after reading that answer.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Code to instantiate

```
Fragment f = new Fragment();

ArrayList<IconsCategory> category = Utils.getCategory();
ArrayList<IconItem> icons = category.getIconsArray();

f = IconsFragment.newInstance(icons);

return f;
```

Code in fragment to create the instance:
I know `args.putArrayList()` method doesn't exist, I just wrote it to show how I expect to be able to code it.

```
public static IconsFragment newInstance(ArrayList<IconItem> list) {
    IconsFragment fragment = new IconsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putArrayList(list);   // here's where the code is supposed to go 
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

IconsCategory class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IconsCategory {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<IconItem> iconsArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public IconsCategory(String name, ArrayList<IconItem> iconsArray) {
        this.name = name;
        this.iconsArray = iconsArray;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public ArrayList<IconItem> getIconsArray() {
        return iconsArray.size() > 0 ? this.iconsArray : null;
    }

}
```

IconItem class:

```
public class IconItem {

    private String name;
    private int resId;

    public IconItem(String name, int resId){
        this.name = name;
        this.resId = resId;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getResId(){
        return this.resId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using Serializable, implementing Parcelable is is the preferred route on Android (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html):

IconItem.java

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class IconItem implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private int resId;

    public IconItem(String name, int resId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.resId = resId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getResId() {
        return this.resId;
    }

    @Override public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeInt(resId);
    }

    public static final Creator<IconItem> CREATOR = new Creator<IconItem>() {
        @Override
        public IconItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            String name = in.readString();
            int redId = in.readInt();
            return new IconItem(name, redId);
        }

        @Override
        public IconItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new IconItem[size];
        }
    };
}
```

IconsCategory.java

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IconsCategory implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<IconItem> iconsArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public IconsCategory(String name, ArrayList<IconItem> iconsArray) {
        this.name = name;
        this.iconsArray = iconsArray;
    }


    public static final Creator<IconsCategory> CREATOR = new Creator<IconsCategory>() {
        @Override
        public IconsCategory createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            String name = in.readString();
            ArrayList<IconItem> icons = new ArrayList<>();
            in.readTypedList(icons, IconItem.CREATOR);
            return new IconsCategory(name, icons);
        }

        @Override
        public IconsCategory[] newArray(int size) {
            return new IconsCategory[size];
        }
    };

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public ArrayList<IconItem> getIconsArray() {
        return iconsArray.size() > 0 ? this.iconsArray : null;
    }

    @Override public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeTypedList(iconsArray);
    }
}
```

IconsFragment.java

```
public static IconsFragment newInstance(IconsCategory category) {
    IconsFragment fragment = new IconsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("category", category); 
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: But this sends an IconCategory to the fragment, and I need to send an ArrayList<IconItem> how could I do it with parcelable?

Comment: Look correctly to the `IconsCategory` Class. This class holds a `List` of `IconItem` which you get via `IconCategory.getIconsArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

Implement Serializable in IconItem class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class IconItem implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private int resId;

    public IconItem(String name, int resId){
        this.name = name;
        this.resId = resId;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getResId(){
        return this.resId;
    }

}
```

then

```
public class IconsFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String KEY = "key";
    public static IconsFragment newInstance(ArrayList<IconItem> list) {
        IconsFragment fragment = new IconsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(KEY, list);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

ArrayList implements Serializable by default so you only need to implement it in your classes.

Comment: But it asks me to implement 2 methods and I don't know what to put in them.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, now I need to assign that value to a new  ArrayList<IconItem> variable in fragment's code. ... I'm using getArguments().getSerializable(KEY); ... But it says 'Incompatible types. Required: ArrayList. Found: Serializable'.... What should I do now?

Comment: try: list = (ArrayList<IconItem>) bundle.getSerializable(KEY);

Comment: It doesn't shows the error, but says "Unchecked cast". Should I worry about it?

Comment: it's only warning. You can get rid of it with @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") before the statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Worked flawlessly.

Comment: Please don't use `Serialzable` and use `Parcelable` instead. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35249279/1231245. And please do not accept the Serialzable answer! This is not the Android way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to create a Listener interface, then simply "listen" for the latest list in the `Fragment` in `onCreate`, `onResume`, etc.

Here is an example of my implementation, let me know if you need help seeing the pieces: https://goo.gl/gNJFTV

Notice the implementation of `GetLogListener` found in `MainActivity` and `DailyViewFragment`

Answer (score -2):

This will create your new Fragment and allow you to pass in the ArrayList when you create the Fragment. With this you do not have to make everything Parcelable. If you want to be able to pass you POJOs back and forth then use the Parcelable as Serializable is not a helpful as you get more complicated POJO structures. Also Parcelable has better performance.

```
public IconsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<IconItem> list;

    /** Blank constructor */
    public IconsFragment() {}

    public static IconsFragment createFragment(@Nullable ArrayList<IconItem> list) {
        IconsFragment frag = new IconsFragment();
        frag.init(list);
        return frag;
    }

    public void init(ArrayList<IconItem> list) {
        if (list==null) {
            this.list = new ArrayList<>(0);
        } else {
            // This creates a new list coping your values into the new array
            this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
            // Or this just uses your current list.
            // JUST PICK ON OR THE OTHER.
            this.list = list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might work the first time the fragment is created on the normal flow. But as soon the operating system needs to recreate the fragment (app goes to background and later returns) it will use the default (no arguments) constructor and won't call "createFragment" method you defined. That's why is important to use the Bundle which will be used by Android to recreate the fragment