# Instantiate a fragment with a Custom Object Array List part II

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hi I searched for this question in stackoverflow.com and I found a this post

[Instantiate a fragment with a Custom Object Array List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247641/instantiate-a-fragment-with-a-custom-object-array-list)

And all the answers are Serializer or Parceable, I made this soluction.

My question, is a good Idea or is a bad practice?.

The Object IconItem

```
public class IconItem {

private String name;
private int resId;

public IconItem(String name, int resId){
    this.name = name;
    this.resId = resId;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public int getResId(){
    return this.resId;
}
```

}

The fragment

```
public class IconsFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<IconItem> myList

public static IconsFragment newInstance(ArrayList<IconItem> list) {
    IconsFragment fragment = new IconsFragment();

    myList = list;

    return fragment;
}
```

}

with this I pass the ArrayList when I instance the fragment.

For me work with a RecyclerView in other Fragment.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad practice, as you are passing an entire list of custom object to the initialzer method of the fragment, and yes, most of the post will guide to make it serializable or parcelable because:

For serialization, 
creates short term storage of almost-arbitrary objects refer [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191269/java-serialization-advantages-and-disadvantages-use-or-avoid)

For Parcelable: 
on the other hand is much of an Android SDK thing.

You can see good SO posts about Parcelable vs Serializable and a good one[here](https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development)

Parcelable and serialization both help in marshalling and unmarshalling the java objects, hence saving heap space. So you objects are not passed directly they are compressed (sort of, not really) and then forwarded
hence extensively recommeded.

And as far as why your approach is not good and recommended, you are sending and entire array of custom objects over a method, if your array list size is too big, you might encounter an OOM.

Sending a huge array list over a parcelable is also not recommended, as it throws a transaction exception, which looks something like this:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1791812 bytes
```

But for small custom object lists (<5000) i dont think parcelable gives any errors. though also depends on how huge the custom objects are!

Comment: This is a good form?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/35247728/6669818

I need pass ArrayList from Activity to a Fragment

Comment: yes it is, because, you are not copying 2 arrays, also the handover of objects from one class to another is serialized, in this case. though parcelable is more recommended.

Comment: A question, when you pass 5000 objects?, if you go to fill a RecyclerView, the information come with a filter from the SQL. 
Ok, I understand the code will be optim,
but a small list or a simple app?, What method consumed more memory and CPU the serializer or my sample?.
Thanks for the answer and time my friend, sorry my English I speak Spanish.

Comment: Yes, if you have values around 5000, better use an SQL Db. 
The serializer method used a bit more of CPU but is memory efficient, and the one you thought of also uses CPU to perform array copy and instace creation and also uses a lot of memory. I hope this helps!